# Appbar guidance results in "Invalid qualifier: SCALE-240"

Tags: windows-store-apps, appbar, win-universal-app

The [Windows universal app guidance for app bars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx) suggests you include app bar icons are 100 scale (32x32), 140 scale (45x45) and 240 scale (77x77) icons.

[image: Screen grab from guidance]

The issue is that when I include a 240 scale I get the following warning when I compile: Invalid qualifier: SCALE-240

It seems to me that the scale is not supported. My question then is should I include it, remove it or change to a different scale (perhaps 180)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale-240 is recommended for Windows Phone apps and works there (the default templates provide Scale-240 assets). Windows Store apps typically use scales-80,100,150, and 180. See [How to name resources using qualifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965324(v=win.10).aspx#scale)

The Scale-240 asset won't cause any problems at runtime, but will be ignored on Windows. You'll definitely want to include other scales instead or with it.